# Linux mkfs.f2fs Error: Device size is not sufficient for F2FS volume

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, mkfs, f2fs

I am trying to mount an F2FS file system on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine running Linux version 4.4.178+. When I try to run:

```
sudo mkfs.f2fs /dev/sda2
```

the system returns:

```
F2Fs-tools: mkfs.f2fs Ver: 1.12.0 (2018-11-12)

Info: Disable heap-based policy
Info: Debug level = 0
Info: Label = FirstTry
Info: Trim is enabled
Info: [/dev/sda2] Disk Model: VBPX HARDDISK
Info: Segments per section = 1
Info: Sections per zone = 1
Info: sector size = 512
Info: total sectors = 2 (0 MB)
Info: zone aligned segment0 blkaddr: 512
    Error: Device size is not sufficient for F2FS volume
    Error: Failed to prepare a super block!!!
    Error: Could not format the device!!!
```

I believe it has to do with the number of total sectors being only 2, but cannot figure out how to change that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `/dev/sda2`?  Do you know why `fsck` is saying “total sectors = 2”?  What do other commands say?  E.g., ``dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/dev/null``

Comment: /dev/sda2 is the target volume to format in F2FS and in this case is the second partition of the first drive. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/F2FS states that the target volume should be of the form /dev/sdxY. dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/dev/null returns 
dd: writing to '/dev/sdb': No space left on device
3884241+0 records in
3884240+0 records out
1988730880 bytes (2.0 GB, 1.9 GiB) copied, 23,9764 s, 82.9 MB/s

Comment: Actually i just tried 

mkfs.f2fs /dev/sdb 

and it was successful. Thank you so much for your help